# why keyframes animation don't work for <a>?

Tags: javascript, html, css-animations

i make a pulsing circular menu
everything else works well, so here is the part where i need to add animation

```css
@import url("https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import "compass/css3";

.menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #0081ee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#0081ee, 0.5);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.5s infinite;
}

.menu-button:hover {
  -webkit-animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    @include transform(scale(0.9));
  }
  70% {
    @include transform(scale(1));
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(#0081ee, 0);
  }
  100% {
    @include transform(scale(0.9));
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#0081ee, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
 <a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x"></a>
```

but nothing happens
what's a problem? tell me please

Answer (score 0):

The `@include`-rule is part of SASS, and is used with SASS identifiers.

What you mean is the `transform`-property. Use it like this:

```css
transform: scale(0.9);
```

Comment: You need to replace the full line that has the `@include`-rule with what I suggested. Further, using the `-webkit-`-prefix is only relevant if you are aiming for backwards-compatibility. It should also work without. Further, not all browsers support features of webkit, hence you should use multiple fallback-properties (or the now-standardized one in this case).

Comment: should my code look like this? 
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform(scale(0.9));
  }
  70% {
    transform(scale(1));
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(#0081ee, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform(scale(0.9));
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#0081ee, 0);
  }
}

Comment: Almost. Now you only need to replace your `transform(scale(x))` to look like this: `transform: scale(x)`

Comment: Oooo, i'm stuuupiiid... thank you soo much!